# WSO2 API Manager Store WebApp is slow

Tags: wso2

I am deploying the WSO2 API Manager based on the published docker-compose available at:

https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim

I've been able to, with a little assistance get everything working as expected, apart from one thing that is troubling: I have no problem accessing Carbon, Publisher or the Store web applikations, however, for some reason, the Store is extremely slow to respond, borderline useless, often timing out or taking minutes to load a simple view. This makes working with the entire solution cumbersome and it will never be acceptable among the potential users.

Apart from setting up the IP-addresses for the components there's nothing changed from the published compose image. I've tried accessing it from various clients, down to using a web browser on the host and it's all the same. The Publisher and Carbon works flawlessly with no performance issues. Does anyone have any idea, I'm a bit at my wits end.

Cheers

Comment: Do you see any errors on the log? If it is about the host, then please follow https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Whitelisting+Hostnames+for+API+Store

Comment: Not specifically related to when this problem is occurring. I've tried running the image on my client machine, where everything works perfectly, but when I take the very same image, upload it to the dev environment (A Ubuntu 18.04 host) and deploy it, I get the described problem, where all the apps except for the Store is working fine.